# How to write a function that takes a closure as a parameter that takes another closure as a parameter?

Tags: rust

I want to write a function that takes a closure as a parameter which takes another closure as a parameter, something like this:

```
fn test<F: Fn(G), G: Fn()>(f: F) {
    let print = || {
        println!("hello");
    };
    f(print);
}

fn main() {
    test(|print| {
        print();
    })
}
```

but this gives this error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:5:7
  |
1 | fn test<F: Fn(G), G: Fn()>(f: F) {
  |                   - expected this type parameter
2 |     let print = || {
  |                 -- the found closure
...
5 |     f(print);
  |     - ^^^^^ expected type parameter `G`, found closure
  |     |
  |     arguments to this function are incorrect
  |
  = note: expected type parameter `G`
                    found closure `{closure@src/main.rs:2:17: 2:19}`
```

Comment: This should have been `F: for <G: Fn()> Fn(G)`, but it seems Rust doesn’t support this yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
fn test<F: Fn(G), G: Fn()>(f: F)
```

This reads "`test` takes an `f: F`, where `F` is a *specific* function type that takes a `G`, where `G` is a *specific* function type". But you don't want `F` to take a specific function type chosen by the caller. You want `F` to take *any* callable function.

In principle, what you *want* to say is this.

```
fn test<F: ∀(G: Fn()) => Fn(G)>(f: F)
```

I'm making up the syntax here, of course, but what you want to say is "for *all* function types `G`, `F` can accept a `G` and do something useful". Rust doesn't have [Rank-2 polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_polymorphism#Higher-rank_polymorphism), so we need to find a workaround.

For one, you could just pay the indirection cost and take a trait object.

```
fn test<F: Fn(Box<dyn Fn()>)>(f: F) {
  let print = || {
    println!("hello");
  };
  f(Box::new(print));
}
```

You've moved the "I don't know what `G` is" problem from compile-time to runtime and just thrown the information into a vtable. This works, and it doesn't change how your function is called from `main`, but it does require a virtual lookup at runtime, which is a very slight performance hit.

Since your closure is *not* capturing (at least, not in this example), you can also just take a function pointer at the second level.

```
fn test<F: Fn(fn())>(f: F) {
  let print = || {
    println!("hello");
  };
  f(print);
}
```

Note the lowercase `fn()` on the inside. This is a [function pointer type `fn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/function-pointer.html), *not* the [immutable callable object trait `Fn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Fn.html).

This restricts your inner function (`print`) to being either an ordinary `fn` or a non-capturing closure, which might be good enough for your use case.

Comment: The trait-object approach doesn't require allocating, the closure can take `&dyn Fn()` instead of `Box<dyn Fn()>`: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3d205875f841b3749760f961c03b0af2

Comment: A function that can take any closure is not necesary at all, the closure only has to take a single type, that of `print`, unfortunately that type is unnamable, and [TAIT doesn't work for closures here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=58bb07e51232c41be9f925e3c4863f2b) (it does work with a `fn print() {…}`). `∀(G: Fn())` would be a workaround to having to name the type though.

Comment: There is already syntax for ∀(…); it’s `for <…>`, but in only works with the lifetime kind, not the type kind (e.g. `F: for <'a> Fn(&'a i32)`). Use of the syntax with the type kind can be *attempted* on unstable (with `#![feature(non_lifetime_binders)]`), but it just crashes the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to what @SilvioMayolo proposed, that is zero-cost but requires changing the caller, is to take a trait instead of a function. Traits are allowed to have generic methods, so this works:

```rust
trait TakesFn {
    fn call<F: Fn()>(&self, f: F);
}

fn test<F: TakesFn>(f: F) {
    let print = || {
        println!("hello");
    };
    f.call(print);
}

fn main() {
    test({
        struct F;
        impl TakesFn for F {
            fn call<G: Fn()>(&self, f: G) {
                f();
            }
        }
        F
    });
}
```